# How do I restrict java function usage in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a project with more than 100 java classes. My case is:
- i have Button.java, DropDown.java, Checkbox.Java, ListBox.java....
- also, some business class that represent a page for my web app with custom functions and mapping for Button.java and DropDown.java
- I want now to be able to use only functions from button and dropdown

An example:

```
public class FieldsProperties extends RHRegion{
    public static void setProperties(String strMap){
        HashMap<String, String> mapProperties = getMapProperties();
        if(strMap.equals("Properties")){
        mapProperties = UISummary.getProperties("UISummary");
        }
        setMapProperties(mapProperties);
        RHRegion.setProperties(strMap);
    }
}
```

so in my scenario i want to be allowed only functions from UISummary.java or just to be notified if it is used another class

Comment: what do you mean? You want the user of your application only to be able to use that?

Comment: @22cos You should edit your question and add the example to the question, instead of as a comment

Comment: Please format this unintelligible mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IllegalType](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#IllegalType) rule from [checkStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/):

> Checks that particular classes are never used as types in variable declarations, return values or parameters.
>
> Rationale: Helps reduce coupling on concrete classes.

Simply add the classes to the list of `illegalClassNames`. You can configure checkStyle to treat the rule violation either as warning or as error.

Note that this does not prevent from **instantiation** - for example, assigning to a parent type is still possible. A better (or additional) rule might be [IllegalInstantiation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#IllegalInstantiation):

> Checks for illegal instantiations where a factory method is preferred.

Assumed that you do not have a factory method for your restricted classes, this would violate all instantiations of classes defined in the `classes` property.
 of that rule
There is also an [IntelliJ plugin for checkstyle](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065) available.

Comment: Well, it would be a long list for illegalClassNames: all other 99 classes from my(inherited) project. A lot easier would be to have something like legalClassName - to list in my class only those I really need. And maybe in the future just add/remove class.

Comment: Can you subclass the allowed classes and put the sub classes in a separate package? That would be useful anyway so that you have a single package which contains the API you are allowed to use. Then, you could use the `IllegalImport` rule from checkstyle to make sure that you do not import the original package by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Without having deeper knowledge of your application, but wouldn't it be much better to rethink your packge / application / class structure to prevent the usage of unwanted functionality?